# update con while y top en sql server

Tags: sql-server, while

tengo el siguiente problema tengo que actualizar una columna de una tabla t1 con información de una columna #t2 son muchos registros como los puedo actualizar por lotes de 1000

```sql
create tabla #tem 
insert into from tabla2 t2

while exists(select top 1 1 from #tem)

select top 1000
from tem2 join t2

update t2 set t2.camp1 = #tem.cam1 
where #tem1_id = t2.id
```

Comment: Si lo queres por lotes, vas a tener que hacer un procedimiento.. igual, si pones top, y no ordenas, va a actualizar siempre lo mismo...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar la cláusula UPDATE junto con TOP y WHILE para actualizar registros en una tabla de manera iterativa hasta que se cumpla una condición. Aquí hay un ejemplo básico:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 1;

WHILE @RowCount > 0
BEGIN
    -- Realiza la actualización en los primeros N registros que cumplan con tu condición
    UPDATE TOP (1000) TuTabla
    SET TuColumna = 'NuevoValor'
    WHERE TuColumna LIKE 'Patron%';  -- Coloca aquí tu condición específica
    
    -- Actualiza el contador de filas afectadas
    SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    -- Puedes agregar un retardo opcional entre las iteraciones si es necesario
    -- WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; -- Retardo de 1 segundo, por ejemplo
END
```

[TOP](https://sqlserverdb.com/sql-select-top/) (1000) limita la actualización a los primeros 1000 registros que cumplen con la condición especificada. Puedes ajustar el número según tus necesidades y el rendimiento de tu base de datos.

@@ROWCOUNT devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última operación de actualización. El bucle [WHILE](https://sqlserverdb.com/sql-while/)E continuará ejecutándose siempre y cuando haya filas afectadas.

Puedes agregar un retardo opcional entre las iteraciones utilizando [WAITFOR DELAY](https://sqlserverdb.com/sql-waitfor/) si es necesario. Esto puede ser útil para evitar un impacto significativo en el rendimiento de la base de datos.

Comment: Esto lo escribiste o lo copiaste de una IA?? ojo, por que las IA estan prohibidas para dar respuesta.. y lo pregunto, porque ese top ahi actualiza siempre los mismos registros...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y pronta respuesta me sirvió mucho